# Change search to obey location, then option for remote

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

How does one specify remote jobs only in a certain state or country?
It looks like the job search does not even consider the location field once you check the bit for **remote work**.  It's understandable since it is in fact remote.

But there should be a way where I can ask for "remote work" in a specific location.  Some places like the current place I am in allow remote work but once in awhile I need to go into the company.

Is there a way to search for remote but include the location?  If not why do we even have a location field - maybe this should be disabled if you've selected remote?

Comment: This is a bug that I started fixing last week and forgot to commit. Basically the query that is generated should be including remote-only jobs (those without a location) and those that are remote in the location you specify. I'll get it fixed up tomorrow.

Comment: Dean ok thanks, that makes more sense.  I'm still waiting on the package you promised me.

Comment: Package? Do you mean from the /jobs rollout last year?

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for the delay, this has finally been pushed to production; we now include jobs that are remote-only (i.e. have no office location) and those that are remote in the location you specify.