# Community should not bump questions that are [status-completed] or [status-declined]

Tags: feature-request, community-user, bump

Today [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) bumped [Change search to obey location, then option for remote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339111/change-search-to-obey-location-then-option-for-remote) for inactivity.  My issue with that is the question is tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).  As such it is completed and does not need any further action from the community.

Can we have the process changed so that Community does  not bump post that are either [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)?

Comment: I've thought of posting this feature request, but figured it wouldn't ever get implemented anyway, and voting is a simple enough workaround.

Comment: @Stijn I just like to give the devs something to do in the next 6 to 8...

Comment: Looks like Jeff declined this already back in 2010.

Comment: @Stijn Slightly different since this one was answered.

Comment: It's just a bit awkwardly worded, OP meant to ask the same as you are asking.

Comment: I see.  And the upvote happened after the bump.  Dupe it is then.